# How do i find residue and singularity of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

the given function is $$f(z)=\sin(e^{\frac1z})$$
i'm also asked to find out the Holomorphic range of it .

Answer (score 1):

Since $sin(x)$ is a "well" function, in the sense that does not have singularities, you need to know the singularities of $e^{1/z}$. (Hint: the only singularity is at z=0, you can make a proof using the Laurent expansion of the function.). So we have one singularity, and in fact is an essential singularity, by Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem we have that the image of $sin(e^{1/z}): \mathbb{C}^{*}\to \mathbb{C}$ is equal to the range of $sin(x)$.

Obs: Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem States that if you have an essential singularity at $z_{0}$, then the image of that function at every neighbothood of $z_{0}$ is dense in the complex plane.

Obs2: See here the range of the complex sin function. http://users.mai.liu.se/hanlu09/complex/domain_coloring-unicode.html#fig:sin

Comment: yeah at $z_{0}=0$ there is a singularity, but i'm unable to calculate the limit to find the residue . @Alexander Agüero

Comment: @JohnnySinns Should just be a Laurent expansion of $e^{1/z}$, then plug this into the Taylor expansion of $\sin(z)$ and extracting the $z^{-1}$ coefficient.

Comment: okay going by this i'm getting 1 @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: $\sin(e^{1/z})=\sin(1+\frac{1}{z}+\cdots )=(1+\frac{1}{z}+\cdots)-\frac{(1+\frac{1}{z}+\cdots)^{3}}{6}$ like this ? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @JohnnySinns Hm...$$\sin(e^{1/z})=\frac1{1!}e^{1/z}-\frac1{3!}e^{3/z}+\frac1{5!}e^{5/z}+\dots=\sin(1)+\frac{\cos(1)}z+\dots$$

Comment: @JohnnySinns Strangely, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+of+sin(e%5E(1%2Fz))

Comment: it says no pole found , but according to the expansion i'm getting a series like this - $$1-\frac{3}{3!}+\frac{5}{5!}-\frac{6}{6!}+\cdots $$ @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @JohnnySinns Note the series expansion of $\cos$ and that $n!=n\times(n-1)!$.

Comment: yeah got it, so the residue would be $2\pi i *\cos(1) $ right? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @JohnnySinns According to my calculations, yes.

Comment: thanks, and what about the holomorphic range ? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @JohnnySinns I know some complex analysis on the side, but I haven't actually learned it for real, so.... hope someone can answer your question $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The range is the unit disk. Because in a neighborhood of 0, the image of the function $e^{1/z}$ is $\mathbb{C}$.